# Error: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, ceph, kubernetes-rook

I am trying to run kafka with kubeless but I get this error pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. I have created a persistent volume using rook and ceph and trying to use this perisistent volume with kubeless kafka. However when I run the code I get "pod has unbound persistent volume claims"

What am I doing wrong here?

## Persistent Volument for Kafka

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: datadir
  labels:
    kubeless: kafka
spec:
  storageClassName: rook-block
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

## Persistent Volume for zookeper

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
  labels:
    kubeless: zookeeper
spec:
  storageClassName: rook-block
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

## Kubeless Kafka

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka
  namespace: kubeless
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9092
  selector:
    kubeless: kafka
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zoo
  namespace: kubeless
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: peer
    port: 9092
  - name: leader-election
    port: 3888
  selector:
    kubeless: zookeeper
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    kubeless: kafka-trigger-controller
  name: kafka-trigger-controller
  namespace: kubeless
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      kubeless: kafka-trigger-controller
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        kubeless: kafka-trigger-controller
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: KUBELESS_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: KUBELESS_CONFIG
          value: kubeless-config
        image: kubeless/kafka-trigger-controller:v1.0.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: kafka-trigger-controller
      serviceAccountName: controller-acct
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: kafka-controller-deployer
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
- apiGroups:
  - kubeless.io
  resources:
  - functions
  - kafkatriggers
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - update
  - delete
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kafka-controller-deployer
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: kafka-controller-deployer
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: controller-acct
  namespace: kubeless
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: kafkatriggers.kubeless.io
spec:
  group: kubeless.io
  names:
    kind: KafkaTrigger
    plural: kafkatriggers
    singular: kafkatrigger
  scope: Namespaced
  version: v1beta1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kafka
  namespace: kubeless
spec:
  serviceName: broker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        kubeless: kafka
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
          value: broker.kubeless
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
          value: "9092"
        - name: KAFKA_PORT
          value: "9092"
        - name: KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE
          value: "true"
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: zookeeper.kubeless:2181
        - name: ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER
          value: "yes"
        image: bitnami/kafka:1.1.0-r0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          tcpSocket:
            port: 9092
        name: broker
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /bitnami/kafka/data
          name: datadir
      initContainers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - chmod -R g+rwX /bitnami
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: volume-permissions
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /bitnami/kafka/data
          name: datadir
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: datadir
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: broker
  namespace: kubeless
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 9092
  selector:
    kubeless: kafka
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: zoo
  namespace: kubeless
spec:
  serviceName: zoo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        kubeless: zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ZOO_SERVERS
          value: server.1=zoo-0.zoo:2888:3888:participant
        - name: ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN
          value: "yes"
        image: bitnami/zookeeper:3.4.10-r12
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: zookeeper
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2181
          name: client
        - containerPort: 2888
          name: peer
        - containerPort: 3888
          name: leader-election
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /bitnami/zookeeper
          name: zookeeper
      initContainers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - chmod -R g+rwX /bitnami
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: volume-permissions
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /bitnami/zookeeper
          name: zookeeper
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: zookeeper
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
  namespace: kubeless
spec:
  ports:
  - name: client
    port: 2181
  selector:
    kubeless: zookeeper
```

## ERROR

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~/infra/ansible/scripts/kubeless-kafka-trigger$ kubectl get pod -n kubeless
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kafka-0                                        0/1     Pending   0          8m44s
kafka-trigger-controller-7cbd54b458-pccpn      1/1     Running   0          8m47s
kubeless-controller-manager-5bcb6757d9-nlksd   3/3     Running   0          3h34m
zoo-0                                          0/1     Pending   0          8m42s
```

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  45s (x10 over 10m)  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times
```

kubectl describe pod kafka-0 -n kubeless

```
Name:           kafka-0
Namespace:      kubeless
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         controller-revision-hash=kafka-c498d7f6
                kubeless=kafka
                statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=kafka-0
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/kafka
Init Containers:
  volume-permissions:
    Image:      busybox
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      chmod -R g+rwX /bitnami
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/kafka/data from datadir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-wj8vx (ro)
Containers:
  broker:
    Image:      bitnami/kafka:1.1.0-r0
    Port:       9092/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Liveness:   tcp-socket :9092 delay=30s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME:  broker.kubeless
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT:       9092
      KAFKA_PORT:                  9092
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE:   true
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:     zookeeper.kubeless:2181
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER:    yes
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/kafka/data from datadir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-wj8vx (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
Volumes:
  datadir:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  datadir-kafka-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-wj8vx:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-wj8vx
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  45s (x10 over 10m)  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times)
```

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54923806/why-do-i-get-unbound-immediate-persistentvolumeclaims-on-minikube and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975887/digitalocean-pod-has-unbound-immediate-persistentvolumeclaims

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working.. For someone who faces the same problem this would be useful..

This uses rook-ceph storage kubeless kafka

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kafka
  namespace: kubeless
  labels:
    kubeless: kafka
spec:
  storageClassName: rook-block
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
  namespace: kubeless  
  labels:
    kubeless: zookeeper
spec:
  storageClassName: rook-block
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka
  namespace: kubeless
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9092
  selector:
    kubeless: kafka
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zoo
  namespace: kubeless
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: peer
    port: 9092
  - name: leader-election
    port: 3888
  selector:
    kubeless: zookeeper
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    kubeless: kafka-trigger-controller
  name: kafka-trigger-controller
  namespace: kubeless
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      kubeless: kafka-trigger-controller
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        kubeless: kafka-trigger-controller
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: KUBELESS_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: KUBELESS_CONFIG
          value: kubeless-config
        image: kubeless/kafka-trigger-controller:v1.0.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: kafka-trigger-controller
      serviceAccountName: controller-acct
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: kafka-controller-deployer
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
- apiGroups:
  - kubeless.io
  resources:
  - functions
  - kafkatriggers
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - update
  - delete
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kafka-controller-deployer
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: kafka-controller-deployer
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: controller-acct
  namespace: kubeless
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: kafkatriggers.kubeless.io
spec:
  group: kubeless.io
  names:
    kind: KafkaTrigger
    plural: kafkatriggers
    singular: kafkatrigger
  scope: Namespaced
  version: v1beta1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kafka
  namespace: kubeless
spec:
  serviceName: broker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        kubeless: kafka
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
          value: broker.kubeless
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
          value: "9092"
        - name: KAFKA_PORT
          value: "9092"
        - name: KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE
          value: "true"
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: zookeeper.kubeless:2181
        - name: ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER
          value: "yes"
        image: bitnami/kafka:1.1.0-r0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          tcpSocket:
            port: 9092
        name: broker
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /bitnami/kafka/data
          name: kafka
      initContainers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - chmod -R g+rwX /bitnami
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: volume-permissions
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /bitnami/kafka/data
          name: kafka
      volumes:
        - name: kafka
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: kafka  
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: broker
  namespace: kubeless
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 9092
  selector:
    kubeless: kafka
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: zoo
  namespace: kubeless
spec:
  serviceName: zoo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        kubeless: zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ZOO_SERVERS
          value: server.1=zoo-0.zoo:2888:3888:participant
        - name: ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN
          value: "yes"
        image: bitnami/zookeeper:3.4.10-r12
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: zookeeper
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2181
          name: client
        - containerPort: 2888
          name: peer
        - containerPort: 3888
          name: leader-election
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /bitnami/zookeeper
          name: zookeeper
      initContainers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - chmod -R g+rwX /bitnami
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: volume-permissions
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /bitnami/zookeeper
          name: zookeeper
      volumes:
        - name: zookeeper
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: zookeeper  
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
  namespace: kubeless
spec:
  ports:
  - name: client
    port: 2181
  selector:
    kubeless: zookeeper
```

Comment: if you were using minikube I assume you were trying to teach yourself if I am not wrong,   recenty faced similar problem but as the error message suggest and following the docs I created PVC which also requried StorageClass. However the question that remains is why are many facing the smae probem? has there been recent update to kubernetes to explicilty define PVC and storage class ?

Answer (score -1):

Got the same error in my minikube. Forgot to create volumes for my statefulSets.

Created PVC. Need to pay attention to storageClassName, check througt availiable (i did it at dashboard).

```json
{
  "kind": "PersistentVolumeClaim",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
   "name": "XXXX",
    "namespace": "kube-public",
    "labels": {
      "kubeless": "XXXX"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "storageClassName": "hostpath",
    "accessModes": [
      "ReadWriteOnce"
    ],
    "resources": {
      "requests": {
        "storage": "1Gi"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got persistence volumes. 
Then i edited statefulSet:

```json
    "volumes": [
          {
            "name": "XXX",
             "persistentVolumeClaim": {
               "claimName": "XXX"
             }
          }
```

Added "persistentVolumeClaim" attribute, dropped pod, waited until new pod created.